# Export-CSV cmdlet rewriting entire CSV during each iteration of a FOREACH statement

Tags: powershell, csv, perfmon

I'm working with some code that is going to take a series of performance counters, and then put the counters in a .csv file that rolls over every time it hits 1MB.

```
$Folder="C:\Perflogs\BBCRMLogs" # Change the bit in the quotation marks to whatever directory you want the log file stored in

$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$1GBInBytes = 1GB
$p = LOTS OF COUNTERS;

# If you want to change the performance counters, change the above list. However, these are the recommended counters for a client machine. 

$num  = 0
$file = "$Folder\SQL_log_${num}.csv"

if( !(test-path $folder)) {New-Item $Folder -type directory}

Get-Counter -counter $p -SampleInterval 2 -Continuous | Foreach {

    if ((Get-Item $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Length -gt 1mb) 
    {
        $num +=1
        $file = "$Folder\SQL_log_${num}.csv"
    }

    $_

} | Foreach-Object { $_ | Export-Csv $file -Force -Append}
```

Right now, it's working quite well. The iteration works fine, and it does create a new file each time the .csv reaches 1MB. However, each .CSV after the first is being created after 2 minutes already at 1MB, causing a new file to be created. I'm not quite sure why this is occurring, although I believe it's because Powershell is just rewriting the entirety of the .csv each time it creates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[I'm posting this as a new answer rather than editing the original because it's completely different. Replacing or appending to the original answer would make the ensuing discussion confusing.]*

What you need to do is use a regex to extract the values from the Readings property of the output of Get-Counter, and manually construct CSV output from the timestamp and those values. Change the last line to this (format according to your preferred style):

```
| %{'"' + (Get-Date $_.Timestamp -f 's') + '","' + (([regex]::matches($_.Readings, '(?<=\\\\.+?:\n)(.+?)(?=\n)') | select -ExpandProperty Value) -join '","') + '"'} | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding ASCII
```

To break that down:

- `(Get-Date $_.Timestamp -f 's')`  This part is not strictly necessary, though I think it will make your results easier to follow. The 's' format puts the date in an ISO 8601 sortable pattern. You could substitute 'u' for another sortable format, or use your favorite custom format string. Or just replace it with **$_.Timestamp** to retain the original format.
- `[regex]::matches($_.Readings,  '(?<=\\\\.+?:\n)(.+?)(?=\n)')`  The regex matches the contents of any line that is preceded by a line that begins with **\\** and ends with **:** (those pesky counter names you wanted to get rid of). Note that I'm using **[regex]::matches**, which performs a global match,  as opposed to **[regex]::match** or **-match**, which will just give you the first match for each string (the Readings property is a single string, so only the first counter reading would be returned).
- `| select -ExpandProperty Value`  Produces an array of all the matches, which you can then join with **","** and surround with **"**'s to produce CSV output.

Since you're not using a conversion function, you also need to construct a header row. Add this line right above the pipeline:

```
`'"Timestamp","' + ($p -join '","') + '"' | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding ASCII`
```

That's assuming that $p is an array (which it should be). If it's a string, then depending on the format you can either use it as-is, or **-split** it and rejoin it in CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to this, to convert each line to CSV format and then append it to the output file:

```
} | Foreach-Object {($_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1] | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding ASCII}.
```

A few notes:

- The `-Encoding ASCII` is not strictly necessary, but you might have trouble with a Unicode CSV file in some applications (Excel, for example, won't open it as a CSV file by default, and everything will be in Column A)
- The reason for the index in `($_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1]` is that `ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` still outputs the header row each time, so you want to grab the second line of the two-line output (`($_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[0]` is the header row)
- Since you're not outputting a header row, you'll need to output one to $file before the loop

Comment: Actually, -append does exist. I'll give -noclobber a shot anyway, because it feels like that might work a little better. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx

Comment: Actually, it occurred to me that the answer I gave you is incorrect. -NoClobber will prevent overwriting, but won't append. Instead, change your last line to this: `} | Foreach-Object {($_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1] | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding ASCII}`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: BTW, the Foreach-Object block at the end looks superfluous to me. Unless I'm missing something, you could just make the last line `} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)[1] | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding ASCII` and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Actually, my previous comments were incorrect, it was just due to the way Excel parsed the data. The actual data it is outputting has the name of the counter exported with each individual counter. That's gonna bloat the log file and make it impossible to parse.

Comment: It's not clear what you're referring to. What was "just due to the way Excel pased the data"? Are you saying that it *is* appending, but the .csv files are reaching the 1MB limit after only two minutes? Can you give an example of what kind of output you're looking for?

Comment: You can get rid of the counter names with a Select-Object filter and a regex replace, but it's not clear what you want to accomplish. The way you have it, all the readings are thrown together in a single multi-line string in the first column. Do you want each reading on its own line (in which case you'd surround the pipeline with `$p | %{ [...] }`), or do you want one line for each time interval, with each counter's reading in a separate column?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. In the original iteration, the .csv starts with a header line that includes all of the counters, and then each subsequent line just starts with a date-time of the counter and the cooked value. When I tried to look at the .csv from the updated code you provided, it only showed one instance of counters. That doesn't matter though, when I looked at the raw data it is all there.

What I'm looking for, specifically, is each counter in its own column and each time interval on its own row.

Comment: The reason for wanting it in that format is because I can more easily load the resulting .csv file into a SQL table, where each SQL table's column will be a specific counter and each row is a different time.

Comment: Okay, that tells me what we're trying to get to. So, the plan of attack is to use a regex to split up the different counter readings and get rid of the counter names and newlines, then output the results in CSV format (which in this case would be easier to just create by adding the appropriate "'s and ,'s than using the conversion functions). I'll figure out the regex and post a new answer.